# SQL User Defined Function to calculate the number of days between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, user-defined-functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION weekdays (DATE1 DATETIME, DATE2 DATETIME) 
    RETURNS INTEGER
    BEGIN 
        RETURN DATEDIFF(day, DATE1, DATE2);
    END
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 3:  BEGIN

What am I missing.  I've tried a number of variations but nothing has solved it yet.  I'm using MySQL.

Comment: [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) takes two arguments. You have 3 in here.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE FUNCTION weekdays (DATE1 DATETIME, DATE2 DATETIME) 
    RETURNS INTEGER
    BEGIN 
        RETURN DATEDIFF(DATE1, DATE2);
    END $$
```

`DATEDIFF` take only two params.

Answer (score 0):

How it worked for me:

```
SELECT A.DOCNUMBR,A.DOCDATE,DATEDIFF(DAY,A.DOCDATE,GETDATE()) AS DAYS_CALC,
  FROM RM_TRANSACTIONS AS A
WHERE A.CURTRXAMNT <> 0
```

The result presents the Document Number, the Document Date and the age of the Document in number of days.

This is very useful if you want to eventually create an Aging Report later in Excel.

Erwin-PR

Comment: The Question is asking for a function, not a SQL